# Ubuntu 18.04 Edge Scrolling won't turn off

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

I have recently upgraded to 18.04 and I can't seem to find a way to turn off edge scrolling on my touchpad. This is weird because when I check synclient it says 
    "VertEdgeScroll = 0" which implies it is off. In addition, I have natural scrolling turn on, but with edge scrolling it seems to be set to the regular and not natural.

Is this just a bug or is there something I might be doing incorrectly?